# Question regarding regression with binary/dummy variable

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

I am currently writing a thesis where I want to do a regression. Now I run into a problem and somehow I dont find any answer to it.

Basicly explained, I have a list of firms and I identified different segments.

Lets say I have 6 segments (Luxury, Upscale, Midscale and so on until Budget).

Now I want to create dummy/binary variables. 1 always means "firms operates in luxury segment".

Now almost all firms cover ***more than*** one segment. 
First I know that I have to include k-1 dummys. I therefore only include 5 dummys of my 6 possible outcomes.

For example:
Firm A is in only luxury and Upscale.
Firm B is only in Midscale and Budget.

My problem is, that all combinations are possible, except all dummys are 0 (does not operate in any segment).

All examples I am able to find, the dummys are always exclusive (for example: It is only in spring avaiable or only in summer. But not "it is available in spring, summer and winter, but not in autumn).

I hope you understand what my problem is. Is it possible to run a regression if more than 1 of the created dummys take the value "1"?

Comment: Haven't you simply got six different predictors then, each of which can be coded with a 0/1 indicator variable independently?

Comment: Agreed with Scortchi. You have six separate binary variables, not one categorical variable. A categorical variable, by definition, has *mutually exclusive* categories, which is not the case for you. You need all six bits of information to convey the possible combinations of segments that a firm can cover.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. That is actually why I am getting more confused the more I search about the problem. Each Firm can operate in all possible segments. What I want to do is this: try to see if a firm operates in Luxury/ is there a significant difference compared to one that does not. If I have 6 predictors, as you say, I would simply inculde all of them in my regression with a binary variable that states "it operates in this segment or not". So Basicly, I am not bound to the k-1 rule for the dummy trap, since I dont have a "categorical variable" ? 

Thank you

Comment: I think I just got what you mean. I have 6 categorical variables (dummys) that have nothing to do with each other in my model. Since I only include one information (luxury on=1/off=0) I have k-1 dummys. And that for each dummy. My misunderstanding was, that all segments are ONE and not 6 different categorical variables! 
As far as I know, there is no problem with including as many dummy variables in a regression, is there?
Thank you very much for your help - sometimes simple thinking mistakes can make the process hard...

Comment: @NicolasGirard: That's right. Note you can also include terms for interactions.

Comment: Yes I thought about interactions terms too, but since I have more other dummy variables (regions, and others) it could get fairly complicated, I might only include some of interest that explain my hypothes the best.

I really appreciate your help, it was a simple mistake in my way of thinking - but it could have missed everything up!

Big Thanks for your help!